# Symfony EntityType - access choice_label after submitting

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have an EntityType field:

```
->add('topic', null, [
     'required' => false,
     'class' => Category::class
])
```

And for new `Category` 's my js tool creates a new select option marked with `__new_option__`:

[image]

So the value to read is not the value. It is the label.

How can I read this value after submission.
I tried `addViewTransformer`, `addEventListener` with `preSetData` and `postSetData`.

But when I get the value - it shows everytime just `__new_option__` but not the value to persist into the database.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I read this value after submission. I tried
> addViewTransformer, addEventListener with preSetData and postSetData.

By reason of the post-data containing the `topic`-field eq '**new_option**'. "It doesn't know anything about the selected value`s label".

I don`t know your implementation, but -> just change-modify the js-behaviour on submitting like:

```
let topicSelection = document.getElementById('SELECTOR');
topicSelection.options[el.selectedIndex].value = topicSelection.options[el.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
//... submitting
```

Comment: Ok. Since the js-tool I use is written by myself. I will implement it there. Like __new_option__new value. So I have not to test against the db in my eventListener to find out if its new. Thank you.